# Symfony forms from entity with additional fields

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

As I know I could create form using form type: `$form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), $user);`

And here is form type:

```php
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
        $builder->add('email', 'email');

        $builder->add('terms', 'checkbox', array(
            'mapped' => false
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\UsersBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_registration';
    }

}
```

So I could add field `term` and don't map it to entity. But what is the way to validate this field? Sure I can do something like `if ($form->get('terms')->getData())` in my controller but I want to use one function `$form->isValid()` to validate all fields (mapped and don't mapped)? May be any validate hooks or events exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's covered in [the *Adding Validation* section of the *Forms* chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation).